# InputStream and ContentLength is missing in microsoft.aspnet.http.abstractions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As my review to the Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, the IFormFile is missing the InputStream and ContentLength in ASP.NET MVC 6, it insteads of OpenReadStream, which is not functioned to respnse to the ConvertToBytes, for example:

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile image)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = null;
        //Then, Read stream in Binary
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);
        imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int) image.ContentLength);
        return imageBytes;

    }
```

Do you know what happen to InputStream and ContentLength? In the IFormFile, are available of OpenReadStream and Length. I don't know how to use it. Do anyone know how to use it. I would like to have similar code as below example:

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile image)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = null;
        //Then, Read stream in Binary
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.OpenReadStream());
        imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int) image.Length);
        return imageBytes;

    }
```

What I have tried below code, but it does't work because of BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.OpenReadStream()) show up System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code with HResult=-2147467261
and the Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.:

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile image)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = null;
        //Then, Read stream in Binary
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.OpenReadStream());
        imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int) image.Length);
        return imageBytes;

    }
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

I call ConvertToBytes in order to add the image file the database field in varbinary datatype, please see code below:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public int UploadImageInDataBase(IFormFile file, PublisherInfosViewModel publisherInfosViewModel)
    {
        publisherInfosViewModel.Image = ConvertToBytes(file);
        var publisherInfos = new PublisherInfos
        {
            PubInfoId = publisherInfosViewModel.PubInfoId,
            PubId = publisherInfosViewModel.PubId,
            Title = publisherInfosViewModel.Title,
            Image = publisherInfosViewModel.Image,
            Description = publisherInfosViewModel.Description,
            Contents = publisherInfosViewModel.Contents

        };
        db.PublisherInfos.Add(publisherInfos);
        int i = db.SaveChanges();
        if (i == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you call `ConvertToBytes`? can you should where you do call `ConvertToBytes` when the exception occur?

Comment: The exception occurred at BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.OpenReadStream()); because the OpenReadStream cannot allow BinaryReader to read the result of filestream.

Comment: And did you check the `IFormFile file`? It seems like `file` is `null`...

Comment: Yes, How to do? Normally, OpenReadStream should give a value after reading to IFormFile file in order to add a data record (1) when the binary result.

Comment: You should further check how you call `UploadImageInDataBase` and figure out why no `file` is uploaded there...

Comment: With Asp.Net Mvc 5, It working fine, please the link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/how-to-upload-and-display-image-in-mvc/